# Capturing file path in JAVA

Tags: java, file, jar, path

I need to design a executable *.jar* which makes two text files, I want that whenever I double click the executable jar, it automatically transfer the file path to a string so that I can use it in my fileWriter up its directory so that I could give the same path for my text files.

currently I had entered the path manually in my code file. which is useless for me.

```
FileWriter write = new FileWriter ("D:/final project/report.txt", false);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter (write);
```

Comment: What do you mean with file path? The same path as where is the JAR? If it is you have just to do new FileWriter("report.txt", false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use `System.getProperty("user.dir")` which will return current directory path.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide relative path rather than absolute path